# Rails & Mailgun: sending mail through a campaign

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailgun

I'm using the [mailgun_rails](https://github.com/jorgemanrubia/mailgun_rails) gem to send out mail from my rails app. I've created a campaign in Mailgun titled 'weekly_digest'.

In my mailer:

```
email = mail(to: subscription.email, subject: "Here is the top rated release this week")
email.mailgun_options = {campaign: 'weekly_digest'}
```

In the Mailgun logs, I can see the mailer getting sent out with no campaign:

```
"campaigns": []
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Have you found something? thanks

Comment: Sorry, I never found a solution..

Comment: Since I post this comment, I thought about this theory: First you have to create a campaign using their API, then you use the new campaign ID with specific messages. That is, you cannot implicitly create a new campaign. Never tried this so I don't write this as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to return the `email` object. See https://github.com/jorgemanrubia/mailgun_rails/blob/f77f73d4357436005049831b06598efbf5e02a61/spec/lib/mailgun/deliverer_spec.rb#L182-L186